# Prevent gsp html escaping for plain text templates

Tags: grails, gsp

I'm trying to use `groovyPageRenderer` to render plain text emails from gsp files, which is working fairly well, except for everything becoming HTML-escaped, which I would like to prevent.

I found some of the relevant configuration options (`grails.views.gsp.codecs.*`), but they can't be used, because I do want escaping for all the rest of the gsp files (i.e. web pages).

Is there some way to create another renderer which will use different options than the default one? Or to set different options for specific render requests? Or to create another view type, which is just like gsp, but allows its own configuration?

Comment: I feel confident there is a better way, but if your pages are small enough you should just be able to call `decodeHTML()` on the result before actually sending it as a message.